# Weird arithmetic/rounding behaviour in Python

Tags: python, math, rounding, floating-accuracy

This little thing has been driving me crazy for the past couple of hours.

Here is my code. I noticed the problem when I used `int()` to round down some numbers. You can see I am printing the float and integer answers side by side for comparison.

```
class Payment:
def __init__(self):
    self.coins = [0.25, 0.5, 1, 3, 15, 75]

def get_change(self, price, payment):
    change = (payment - price) * 100.0
    self.calculate_change(change)

def calculate_change(self, change):
    for coin in self.coins:
        print change / coin, int(change / coin)
```

And in my Main I have:

```
from Temp import Payment

t = Payment()
t.get_change(2.0, 2.80)
```

### So what's the problem you wonder?

From the Main input the value of `change` happens to be 80 and is passed into `calculate_change`. Now, have a look at the output

```
320.0 319
160.0 159
80.0 79
26.6666666667 26
5.33333333333 5
1.06666666667 1
```

**The rounded values are off by 1. That's odd.**

But if I just call the `calculate_change`function in Main like so:

```
t.calculate_change(80)
```

I get what is expected:

```
320.0 320
160.0 160
80 80
26 26
5 5
1 1
```

So the problem lies somewhere in the `get_change` function. What is it about this line that causes the problem?

`change = (payment - price) * 100.0`

Comment: Floating-point numbers are rounded to a limited number of digits for display purposes. If you see `320.0`, that doesn't mean it's exactly 320.

Comment: `print(319.99999999999999999999999999999)` pretty neatly sums up the underlying problem in answer to your question.

Comment: Change your print statement to *print('%.17f %.17f' % (change / coin, int(change / coin)))* to print the floating-point values to more digits -- then you can see what is happening

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that floating point numbers are never represented exactly.

The calculation `change = (payment - price) * 100.0` will not give you `80` exactly but `79.9999999` or `80.00000001`.

When you use `int` on the former, you are just chopping off everything after the decimal and getting `79`.

The solution is to never use inaccurate data types such as float to represent money. Use whole numbers, so instead of  everything in dollars like `2.80`, use cents `280`. Only when you are ready to present the value to the user do you convert to cents to a dollar representation.

Alternatively, you could use something like Python's [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) class, which can represent decimal numbers with a much higher accuracy at the cost of speed, and a little extra code required each time you work with a number.

Comment: "`80` could be represented as `79.9999999` or `80.00000001`." - no, it couldn't. Enter 80, and you will consistently get a floating-point number of value exactly 80. The problem isn't that floating-point numbers are inexact, but that floating-point operations are inexact. Decimal->float conversion and floating-point arithmetic must round their results, since the exact results are frequently unrepresentable.

Comment: @user2357112 revisiting your comment. You state the problem "isn't that floating-point number are inexact" then you state "results must be rounded since the exact results are frequently unrepresentable". Seems to be a contradiction to me

Comment: A floating-point number exactly represents whatever value it represents, but there may not be a floating-point number that exactly represents the value you want. Imagine rounding the square root of the integer 99 to the integer 10; the inexactness here is not a property of the integer 10, but a property of the operation you performed.